# WordPress hook for visiting a post

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am very new to WordPress plugin development.

I have been searching this for a quite a while now but I am currently creating a plugin and I need my plugin to start logging the amount of views a post has had. I already know what I want this part of to do however I am having trouble find out how to a PHP function for when a post is viewed by a visitor to my WordPress site.

Could someone please show me what the WordPress hook/event is to run a function on post view/load? I want to do this without the use of template as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a conditional to check if you are on a post page.

You can do so by using [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/):

```
if (is_single()) {
    // Update your post views here
}
```

If you insist on using filters or hooks, you can use `the_content` filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'update_post_views' );
function update_post_views($content){
    if (is_single()) {
        $id = get_the_ID();
        // Now update your post's views
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I shall when they let me accept it in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

First, let's try to add post views to the dashboard -> posts. First, we add a new column there:

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', function($columns) {
    return array_merge($columns, ['post_views' => 'Views']);
});
```

Then, we are going to show the number of views. We assume that (Like many other guides on the web), there is a meta key `post_views` holding the number of post views.

```
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', function($column) {
    if ($column === 'post_views') {
        $count = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_views_count', true);
        echo empty($count) ? 'no views :(' : "$count view :)";
    }
});
```

You should be able to see this new column on the posts admin table.

[image: post views wordpress]

Finally, we have the real code to update the `post_views` meta every time a post is visited.

```
function jj_count_post_views($content)
{
    if (is_single() && !is_preview()) {
        $postId = get_the_ID();

        update_post_meta(
            $postId,
            'post_views_count',
            (int) get_post_meta($postId, 'post_views_count', true) + 1
        );

        remove_filter('the_content', 'jj_count_post_views');
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'jj_count_post_views');
```

Please notice that the `remove_filter` is necessary, because some plugins use `the_content` filter to do more stuff to the content (like SEO plugins), so `the_content` will be called multiple times. [Thanks to this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/256881/219135).

Also, remove  `&& !is_preview()` if you want to count all the views, even the preview ones.

P.S. Add all those codes inside theme functions.php and it works.